# Google Sheet Apps Script Random Number in 5 Rows no repeat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help with my Google Sheet. I want to create 1 row with 5 columns and they should be filled with random numbers between 1 and 15 (example) with no repeat. I`ve tried it already with the randbetween function.

I formatted the cells with =RANDARRAY(1;5), to give me an output of 1 row and 5 columns but how can I add here the randbetween function with no repeating the numbers from 1-15? And full numbers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

`=TRANSPOSE(SORTN(SEQUENCE(15);5;0;RANDARRAY(15);1))`

In plain English, this reads as follows:

"Create an ordered vertical list of the sequence of numbers from 1 to 15, sort them according to a vertical random array of 15 numbers, return the top 5 results and then transpose the vertical list to a horizontal one."

The `0` tells `SORTN` how to process ties; but since there won't be any, it's just a filler parameter here.

Comment: Wow, that`s cool. Thank you! But how can I change the numbers, I want to change the numbers range between 100-115?

Comment: You're welcome. As to the starting point, there are several ways. Though you figured out a way of your own, here are the two I'd have suggested: `=TRANSPOSE(SORTN(SEQUENCE(15,1,100);5;0;RANDARRAY(15);1))` - or - `=TRANSPOSE(SORTN(100+SEQUENCE(15);5;0;RANDARRAY(15);1))`